# UWP Title Bar Buttons White When Set To Transparent

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Windows 10 Build 18362. Not sure if Windows bug or not, and looking for a solution anyways.

I think I have a bit of a complex issue which requires a process to reproduce. What ends up happening is this:

[image]

The app uses the system title bar (Not a view extended into the titlebar), and on my machine, the system setting to allow accent colors in the title bar is disabled. This is why the caption buttons are blue (the system accent color) but the actual title bar is black. What I expect, and what should happen (as I will prove) is that the caption buttons (minimize, maximize, close) should be black, as the rest of the title bar is.

One of the first things I tried doing to solve the issue (when I first noticed this in my actual application) was to set the background color of the buttons to transparent. This is what happens:

[image]

Entirely white! Okay, now for a reproducible example.

- Create a new UWP application. I used C#, and am not sure this matters, but for completeness, I recommend you do the same.
- Make sure you disable accent color in the title bar in system settings
- Run the default app and notice the behavior of the title bar. *This is the expected behavior, as the caption buttons are black (in dark theme). This is why I believe what I am experiencing is unintended*
- I added Acrylic effect to the XAML page because I had thought this was the issue. It doesn't seem to be, but just for completeness, use the following XAML and C# (changing App1 to your app name, of course):

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlAcrylicWindowMediumHighBrush}">

    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Core;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace App1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            ApplicationViewTitleBar formattableTitleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
            CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = false;
            formattableTitleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
            formattableTitleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
        }
    }
}
```

You should now see what I have in my second screenshot. If you comment out the two lines in `MainPage.xaml.cs` that assign button colors to transparent, you will get what I see in my first screenshot.

Am I missing something? Is this expected behavior? How do I make the caption buttons just follow the rules all the time?

Answer (score 4):

I understand your question, this behavior does seem confusing.

The title bar has a *color layer* that is like the clothes we wear. You can change the color of your clothes at will, but you can't change the color of people.

The title bar itself is white. When you set `ButtonBackgroundColor` to Transparent, the color layer is actually set to be transparent, revealing the original color of the title bar.

Since you are currently a Dark theme, `ButtonForegroundColor` is white, which causes the white background and white text you see. If you set the `TitleColor` of the TitleBar to `Transparent`, you will understand why the `TitleBar` has a color layer.

Comment: I figured, but why does it go to accent color in the third "phase" when I comment out the transparency? That's what really convinces me that this is an issue and not normal. Accent color should not appear at all if it is disabled in system settings.

Comment: You can try to redeploy after uninstall the app. The changes you made to the `TitleBar` in the second phase will affect your next phase of test results.